# Let the user input the name again

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a game. So when making the name, I need help making it so once a player says no or anything else it will ask for them to input a name in again. But I cant seem to find a way!

```
input("Disclaimer: To be able to continue through text press Enter")
player_name =  input("What's your name? ")
name = input('Do you want to keep the name' + player_name + '? (No or Yes?)')
if name == 'yes' or 'Yes':
  input('Ok then ' + player_name + ', Enjoy the game!!!')
input('Weclome ' + player_name + ', to planet')
print ('T')
print ('S')
print ('E')
print ('')
print ('0')
print ('6')
input("")
print ('Here we shall learn many things about our know...')
input("")
print ('SYSTEM MALFUNCTION: Core heating, bifunctional cooler has been dammag g g g g')
input("")
print ('Oh no, there seemes to be a problem, let me see if I ca')
print ('SYSTEM ALERT: Ejecting all passengers!!!')
input("")
print ('Oh no, no, no, no, NO, this is not supposed to happen!')
input("")
print ('(A helmet is put onto your head, it fills with fresh oxygen. The bottom area of the passenger seat opens to the colorful Planet of TSE below you)')
input("")
input(player_name + " Are... Are you there?")
```

Comment: You need to use a loop. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm).

Comment: Ok, how do I put into my work? Can you edit for me and I may be able to see how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it into a loop like this

```
name = 'no'
while (name.lower() == 'no'):
  player_name =  input("What's your name? ")
  name = input('Do you want to keep the name' + player_name + '? (No or Yes?)')
input('Weclome ' + player_name + ', to planet')
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything under a `while True:` and if they say no then put `continue` to reach the next "iteration"

```
while True:
    answer = input("yes or no?")
    if answer == "yes":
        print("ok")
    if answer == "no":
        continue
```